# How I can use array.contains in entity framework by c#?

Tags: c#

I need to Use array.contains method with two parameter that one off them is int?.
how can i use?

```
  string[] role = Roles.GetRolesForUser(Membership.GetUser().UserName)
                       .ToArray();
  int[] ProcessId = biz.Context.tblRoleProcess
                    .Where(x => (role.Contains(x.Role) || 
                            role.Contains("Administrators")) && 
                            x.Measure == true)
                    .Select(x => x.ProcessId).ToArray();

return GetQuery(filterExpression, Columns)
                    .Where(x => ProcessId.Contains(
                            {x.ProcessID,x.ParentProcessID}))
                     .OrderBy<Models.tblProcess>(sortExpression)
                     .Skip(startRowIndex)
                     .Take(maximumRows);
```

Comment: (*Read* and *post* error messages.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
return GetQuery(filterExpression, Columns)
            .Where(x => ProcessId.Contains(x.ProcessID)
                             || ProcessId.Contains(x.ParentProcessID))
            .OrderBy<Models.tblProcess>(sortExpression)
            .Skip(startRowIndex)
            .Take(maximumRows);
```

**UPDATE**

You can define the `ProcessId` as `int?[]` or more better as `IEnumerable<int?>`

```
IEnumerable<int?> ProcessId = biz.Context.tblRoleProcess
                                 ...
                               .Select(x => (int?)x.ProcessId);
```

or change where as:

```
.Where(x => ProcessId.Contains(x.ProcessID)
               || x.ParentProcessID.HasValue
               ? ProcessId.Contains(x.ParentProcessID)
               : false);
```

Comment: @asieh What you mean? What type of `GetQuery` returns?

Comment: this return an  IQueryable<tblProcess> , i try your answer but i have compile error:"Instance argument: cannot convert from 'int[]' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<int?>' "

Comment: @asieh I mean how defined the `tblProcess`?

Comment: @asieh Try define the `ProcessId` as `int?[]`.

Comment: that is a tree. each process maybe has a parent then "ParentProcessID" is not null. if one process hasn't parent ParentProcessID is null

Comment: that is imposible because process is int and not int?

Comment: @asieh, Why you think so? Try `.Select(x => (int?)x.ProcessId).ToArray();`

Answer (score 0):

`Contains` is not a method defined above array, but above `IEnumerable<T>`. It has two overloads and is well documented on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

First overload (the one you are using) accepts Integer and uses default comparer, that means, two equal integers are

The other overload is with adding a IEqualityComparer instance, which is not really useful in this case.

The most optimal way to use here is not via contains, but via `Any` - you may use `Contains` as suggested in other answers, but that will be less effective:

```
return GetQuery(filterExpression, Columns)
   .Where(x => ProcessId.Any(processIdItem => processIdItem == x.ProcessID || processIdItem == x.ParentProcessId ))
   .OrderBy<Models.tblProcess>(sortExpression)
   .Skip(startRowIndex)
   .Take(maximumRows);
```